# Flask redirect not working at all on repl.it

Tags: python, flask

On repl.it, running flask works fine with something like

```
@app.route("/home")
def home():
  return render_template("home.html")
```

As the home template is rendered in the inspector
[image: Home template is rendered]

However, running

```
@app.route("/")
def base_route():
  return redirect(url_for("home"))

@app.route("/home")
def home():
  return render_template("home.html")
```

Fails to render the page. No errors/exceptions are thrown.

[image]

Is this an issue with repl, or is the code just wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on replit inspector side.

If you try with curl, you will see the redirect happens to url '/home'.

Also, in the upper right button of the inspector
there is button that let you open your website/web app in a separate tab or window. There, from a regular browser window, the redirect will work. Or make index/root render template and redirect `\home` page to index\root, the problem seems to be specific to the root url.

I think you can discuss it in replit talk, it looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Still doesn't redirect, although ill close the question since it appears that repl should work at least in theory

Comment: I also had issues with on pane window, but redirect was working from a separate windows. Perhpaps debugging view is programmed to render error message whenever non 200 status is generated on index/root

Comment: No app is completely defect free, seems like a minor bug.